After installing legacy Nvidia drivers my screen goes black
I tried to install nvidia drivers with a method that braoult shared in this post nvidia-340 driver on Ubuntu 20.04
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-340
sudo apt install xorg-modulepath-fix

After typing the commands that he gave and restarting my laptop giant Nvidia logo popped out on my screen and then it went black with a blinking cursor at the top. How to repair that?
Video showing the issue
I also added this to my grub configuration file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"

And this to my module configuration file
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist nouveau

Text terminal mode works fine
